# Are family courts prejudiced against men?

Tags: family-law, court

Does family court really hate men and fathers? Seems to be a common thought on the internet.

Is it really true the only right a man has towards his kids is the right to pay for everything?

I really wonder how true this widespread idea is?

Comment: Courts do not hate anyone because courts are institutions, not people.

Answer (score 3):

Family court does not hate men, but there have been historical biases in the law that were anti-male. The current standard is to not favor one sex over the other, thus a woman could be ordered to pay a man alimony, a man could be granted sole custody of a child, and so on. More likely, both parents would be given shared custody (meaning rights and responsibilities). The one most conspicuous sex-based legal asymmetry has a well-known natural explanation – the difference in assumptions regarding maternity vs. paternity (I don't know of any jurisdiction that has a provision for contesting maternity of a child).

Comment: Is the term we are all equall under the law not a founding principle? Legal asymmetry just sounds like discrimination due to gender to me.

Comment: @NeilMeyer A founding principle of what country? Your question does not indicate where you are asking from.

Comment: A strange case of contested maternity  https://embryo.asu.edu/pages/case-lydia-fairchild-and-her-chimerism-2002

Comment: Further, when children are involved, the decisions made are those perceived to be in the best interest of the child. Until recently, rightly or wrongly, most men did not stay at home for child-rearing purposes. Mothers, to varying degrees and for varying lengths of time, did. And a child requires care, regardless of any culture war issues going on. Thus, child custody generally went to the woman and child support payments were the responsibility of the man.